# Ionic 2 Google Maps:: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 and trying to load google map using its JS API.
Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class MapPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  latitude : any;
  longitude : any;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams) {   

    this.platform = platform;    
    this.initializeMap();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.initializeMap();
  }  

  initializeMap() {    
       this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       var minZoomLevel = 12;

       this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           zoom: minZoomLevel,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });

       var position = new google.maps.LatLng("23.032612699999998", "72.56187790000001");
       var dogwalkMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: "Testing"});
       dogwalkMarker.setMap(this.map);
   });

   } 

}
```

I have also added reference of the JS in my index.html file before cordova.js:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton side="left">  
    <ion-title  style="margin-left: 0px;"><span class="menuTitle">Map</span></ion-title>    
  </ion-navbar>

 </ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

The code does not display any error but when I try to load this page it displays error like:

**Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mapElement`

**Typescript** file

```
let minZoomLevel = 12;
let mapOptions = {
   zoom: minZoomLevel,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

Comment: @Aparna, You can mark this as an answer, So other can get help from this post. Thanks.